# SNMP : How to find a mac address in the network?

Tags: perl, networking, snmp

I've wrote a Perl script to query devices (switches) on the network, it's used to find an mac address over the LAN. But, I would like to improve it, I mean, I have to give to my script these parameters:

1. The @mac searched
2. Switch' IP
3. Community

How can I do to just give IP and community ?
I know that it depends on my network topology ?
There is a main stack 3-switches (cisco 3750), and after it's linked to other ones (2960), in cascade.
Anyone has an idea ?

Edit : I would like to not specify the switch.
Just give the @mac and the community.

Comment: What improvement do you want? Please elaborate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to solve two problems... Where will the script send the first query... Then, suppose you discover that a mac address was learned through port 1/2/1 on that switch and that port is connected to another switch.  Somehow your script must be smart enough to query the switch attached to port 1/2/1.  Continue the same algorithm until you do not have a switch to query.

What you are asking for is possible, but it would require you to either give the script network topology information in advance, or to discover it dynamically with CDP  or LLDP. CDP always carries the neighbor's ip address... Sometimes you can get that from LLDP.  Both CDP and LLDP have MIB objects you can query.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two scripts basically.  You already have a script to gather your data, but it takes too long to find a single MAC.  Presumably you have a complete list of every switch and it's IP address.  Loop over them all building a database of the CAM table.  Then when you need to search for a MAC, just query your pre-built database.  Update it about once an hour or so and you should maintain pretty accurate results.  You can speed the querying of several devices by running multiple snmp walks in parallel.